# Why isn't the Publish.htm file being created?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to create a ClickOnce deployment of a WPF app, using VS 2019. I'm testing it by having it create the Publish.htm file in a website on my machine. Here's what I have in the project's Publish Options tab:

[image]

However, when I publish from VS 2019, the publish.htm file does not get created on the website. The web.config file is there, but that's all that's there. Why isn't it creating the publish.htm file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If test via iis, you need to fill the `Publishing Folder Loaction` with the physical path of iis website.

[image]

The setting of iis website,

[image]